# structs and segmentation fault

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
    typedef struct tnode *pad;
    struct tnode{
    int data;
    pad left;
    pad right;
    };
    pad p=NULL;
    p=malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
    (p->data)=5;
    (p->left)=malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
    (p->left)->data=4;
    (p->right)=malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
    (p->right)->data=7;
    printf("\nroot is %d right %d left %d",p->data,(p->left)->data,(p->right)->data);
```

I ran this code and I got a segmentation fault
The code isn't doing something specific, I am just wondering why the segmentation fault.

Comment: Where is it segfaulting? Have you run this under a debugger?

Comment: Is there any reason you did not check for the success of `malloc()`?

Comment: Totally unrelated to your problem, but can I ask why you print a newline *first* in your output, but not after? Because the output would normally end up on a new line anyway, and if run stand-alone in a console the prompt may be at the end of the output as no newline may automatically be added. Also, since `stdout` (which `printf` uses) by default is line-buffered, it means output will be written on newline, and if you don't have a trailing newline followed by a big pause, the output will not be written.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me, gcc version 4.8.2. Apart from leaks, obviously. What compiler are you using? Can you post us the output from `valgrind`?

Comment: @g.tsh did you mean `gdb`?

Answer (score 1):

I tried running it on ideone.com and it works fine, (the printf() function prints what it is supposed to print,) then *afterwards* it gives a "Runtime error".

Then I added a "return 0" at the end and it works fine without any error.

Supply the right arguments to the compiler to have it give you proper warnings for a multitude of common programming errors.  In your case, you specified your main() function incorrectly, (it is supposed to return 'int',) but the compiler was compiling it in traditional C mode, so it did not warn you about that.  Then, since the prototype was missing a return type, the compiler did not warn you that you were missing a return statement, either.  You will save yourself from a lot of trouble if you start using `-Wall` (or whatever other flag your compiler understands as "enable all warnings".)

Comment: Not this code any code on ideone expects `return 0`

Comment: @mike No offense, but this answer is a better fit for a comment.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I agree with you, but now I added the advice part, which contains an explanation.  I hope you would agree that it is now suitable as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good and the only reason you might see a crash is because the `malloc()` might have failed and you are trying to access the unallocated memory.

```
p=malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));

if( p != NULL)
{
   //Do your stuff
}
else
return 1;
```

Similarly check the return values for the rest of your `malloc()` and once done using the memory please do free it `free(p)`

PS: `main()` should be `int main()`